# Where to change link in checkout payment information tab. Enterprise 1.13.1.0

Tags: checkout, payment, gift-card

There is one line within the checkout process under Payment Information that says: "To add or remove gift cards, click here."

I literally just need to change the wording of this and possibly the styling. But I cannot find anywhere that it would be. I assumed it would be in the template files but everywhere I've looked came up empty.

Any help is appreciated - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the text by using magento's translate. In your current package add the translate.csv

> app/design/frontend/{package_name}/{theme_name}/locale/{locale_type}/translate.csv

You will need to find what locale you using by logging into magento backend then

> System > Configuration > General > General > Locale Options

Inspect the Locale and find the value e.g en_AU
Change the locale_type

In the translate.csv Enter the sentence outputed by magento and then enter the sentence you want e.g

> "To add or remove gift cards, click here.", "Add/Remove Gift Cards"

More Info: http://blog.belvg.com/editing-magento-translate-csv-file.html

Hope this helps